# make this code run without using anonyomous function

Tags: javascript, function

so here is my js code http://jsfiddle.net/f653jnm0/

```
<body>
<button id="textChanger">change first div text</button>

<div id="firstdiv"> this is some text</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("textChanger").onclick=function() {document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML='blabla'};

</script>
```

when you click the button it changes the text.   i was wondering why do we need to use anonymous function to make it work? cant we run the code without it? like shown below.

http://jsfiddle.net/hjavw3h5/1/

```
<body>
<button id="textChanger">change first div text</button>

<div id="firstdiv"> this is some text</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("textChanger").onclick=document.getElementById('firstdiv').innerHTML='bla bla bla';

</script>
```

in this case the js code is run defaultly and text is changed without interaction with the button.
i just started learning js, so your help would be appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: `onclick` is expected to be a function, that's why you have to assign a function.

Comment: Have you checked yourself once whether the second link is working or not!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i was wondering why do we need to use anonymous function to make it work?

Because you have to give the browser / engine something that can be executed when the event happens. Functions allow you to do that.

**Note:** The function doesn't have to be anonymous, it can also be named:

```
function handler() {
    // handler code here
}

document.getElementById('target').onclick = handler;
```

> cant we run the code without it?

No (at least not on click).

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is only half true.

You need a **function** because (I assume) you want to change the text when you click, not when you define the event handler. Since computers can't still read programmer's mind there has to be syntax sugar to distinguish between both cases:

1. Here's some code, run it now
2. Here's some code, run it later

Functions (or similar constructs) already exist in almost all languages because code reuse is basic to write any complex piece of software. Being able to pass function references around is a clean and useful extension that solves that need.

But it doesn't have to be **anonymous**.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for helpful replies . if got it wright, in Javascript, because .onclick is EVENT HANDLER, the browser expects (only) FUNCTION to come next, to define what that event handler triggers.
but not in the case if we write inline script like this one. http://jsfiddle.net/he0rspdz/ p.s the code below does not show correctly use jsfille link instead.

```
        <body>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('firstdiv').innerHTML='bla bla bla';" id="textChanger">change first div text</button>
<div id="firstdiv"> this is some text</div>
</body>
```